# particle emitter emitting a collection with an object and spot lights

Tags: particles, lighting, parent, collections

I've built a street and I want cars to drive along that street.

I've decided to do that with a particle emitter, emitting objects (the cars I've modelled beforehand). This works. But now I would like to add lights to the cars, which move along with the cars as they get emitted (I'd like to see light cones on the street).

I've tried that with spot lights, attaching them to the sample car and putting that car with the spot lights into a collection. When I set up the emitter like that: *Particles > Render > Render As > "Collection"*, the emitter emits first the car und second the spot light, but never together (attached to one another).

When I check the box *"Whole Collection"*, nothing shows up anymore. The emitted car with the spot lights (the whole collection) just disappears. I've also tried parenting the spot lights to the car and then *Render As > "Object"* again, but then just the car gets emitted. I can't really find a solution. Can anybody help?

Comment: "When I check the box "Whole Collection", nothing shows up anymore. The emitted car with the spot lights (the whole collection) just disappears." This should not happen and is what you need to do (parenting is not relevant in that regard). Can you share your blend file?

Comment: @taiyo Okay, while setting up the file to share it, I've noticed that it actually works. The collection (car and spot lights) doesn't disappear when I check the box "Whole Collection", **BUT** it gets emitted far off were it should be. And I fail to understand why that is. Cause when I tell it to emit just the object for example, it gets emitted right from where the emitter is. [Here is the file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hcMDHAi6jxRgNT-WS_opQ8IRhW7MBb-N/view?usp=sharing) Emitter "car3-emitter1" should emit collection "car3" at the same spot like it does with object "car3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enable *Whole Collection*, Blender emits objects in their correct relative location to each other - the parenting of headlights to car is irrelevant in this case.

So in order to ensure that all objects keep their relative positions, Blender needs a mutual reference point for comparison. Since the parenting is not relevant, the world center becomes the point of reference. Your car (and the headlights) are placed with an offset from the world center, so this offset is kept while emitting the whole collection.

When you switch from *Whole Collection* to *Object*, the object's origin is the reference point since there is no relative location to other objects to be kept.

Long story short: to make it work with the collection, select the car and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to reset the car's location to the world's center.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot! It works now! When I select the car and the lights and press Alt+G, the location of each object gets resetted. When I select just the car and press Alt+G, just the car's location gets resetted without the lights. So I also have to parent the lights to the car to make it work.

Comment: I didn't say you should press Alt+G on the lights.  Parenting helps to keep them in place when the car is moved - but it does not matter for the emitting particles. If you had put the lights in place when the car was already in the world's center, you would not have to parent them to the car for the particles to work correctly. But parenting helps when you want to move the car somewhere and do not want to have to select the lighs as well.